# Using ES Module packages in Azure Typescript Function

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, commonjs, esmodules

I am unable to use the package [p-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-map) in my Azure Function. I get the following error:

```
Worker failed to load function: 'serverless' with function id: '<id>'.
Result: Failure
Exception: Worker was unable to load function serverless: 'Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module <es-module> from /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4483/workers/node/worker-bundle.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4483/workers/node/worker-bundle.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.'
```

The project is created by following [the steps in Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-typescript?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbrowser). The following is in the index.ts:

```js
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import pMap from "p-map";
import got from "got";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    const sites = [
        'https://avajs.dev',
        'https://github.com'
    ];

    const mapper = async site => {
        const {requestUrl} = await got.head(site);
        return requestUrl;
    };

    const result = await pMap(sites, mapper, {concurrency: 2});
    

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: result
    };

};

export default httpTrigger;
```

My tsconfig.json looks like following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es2020",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Lastly, this is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "azure-functions-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "got": "^12.0.4",
    "p-map": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

[p-map is strictly an ES Module and cannot be used in CommonJS projects.](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c)

Am I missing something or is it just not possible to use ES Module packages in Azure Functions? Thanks in advance.

GitHub repository of aforementioned code to test things out locally: [azure-functions-test](https://github.com/Ensar025/azure-functions-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by renaming my index.ts file to index.mts. This built a index.mjs file (after running `npm run build`) in my dist folder which fixed the issue.

One thing to note is that you also have to edit your function.json's scriptFile key so it uses your .mjs file instead of non-existing .js file.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/packages.html#determining-module-system) on Node.js' website, specifying `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` should also indicate if Node should use ESM.

Here's what I did to get ESM working for my functions in my Function App:

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  }
}
```

Some relevant function app settings:

`WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`: `~16` (To run using Node.js 16 runtime)
`FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION`: `~4`

Then make sure to import your ES-style exports with a `.js` extension if your original extension is `.ts`. So if you have a file called `custom.ts` that has exports, then you should import them as `import { something } from "custom.js";`.

And for any npm packages that use default exports (CommonJS style), you should import the package using its default export, i.e. `import * as pkg from "pkg";`.

Relevant links:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/104

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version#ecmascript-modules (Note that this doc talks about importing your ESM exports with a `.mjs` extension but I didn't have to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

I used the `tsup` bundler with no compromises (no ugly .js or .mjs extensions in source code, just pure ESM). I am using the Azure Functions v4 programming model, but i am sure a few tweaks would make it work for the previous programming model aswell (the one using `function.json`-files).

Here is what i did:

1. Remove `"type": "module"` from `package.json`
2. Install `tsup`

   ```
   npm i tsup -D
   ```
3. Add `tsup.config.ts`

   ```
   import { defineConfig } from 'tsup'

   export default defineConfig({
       // Entry file(s) to start building from.
       entry: ['src/**/*.ts'],
       // To output .mjs files
       format: 'esm',
       // Optional: Include external packages inside the bundle. This was nescessary for a monorepo package in my case.
       noExternal: ['@monorepo/package'],
       // Optional: Empty dist directory before build
       clean: true,
   })
   ```
4. Modify `package.json`

   ```
   {
       "main": "./dist/functions/*.mjs",
       "scripts": {
           "build": "tsup",
           ...
       },
       ...
   }
   ```